# Python numpy reshape issues

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am working with machine learning and numpy and having issues with the `np.reshape()` function.  My data sizes are reading in the variable console as Dataframe(22,5), x(21,4),x_lately(1,4), y(22,). I tried reshaping them with `np.reshape(22,5)` since that is the dataframe size and it is giving me this error:

> ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

I presume I am either not understanding something or there is something wrong with my system.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: which dataset are you trying to reshape? And can you clarify that you have 4 different datasets?

Comment: Your reshape operation may not be possible, because you can't just change total entry of a DataFrame.  For example, for a (3,5) DataFrame, you can change it to (5,3), (15,1) or (1,15) DataFrame, not (3,3) or (5,5) DataFrame.

Comment: Hello, i have only one dataset,  i presume i should reshape the (21,4) to (22,)?

Comment: 21*4 = 84, But 84 is not divisible by 22. Now, you should get the hint.

Comment: hm new to this trying to get a hang of the whole thing. so what do you suggest?

Comment: A shape of (21,4) means there are 84 items (take their product).  A new shape must have the same product.   Do you understand what the shape means?

Comment: Yea i do,i really am just confused on which one to reshape i guess.

Comment: Yea it is sounding impossible, any help? and why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to describe your data better.

I can imagine the pieces fitting together:

```
Dataframe(22,5), x(21,4),x_lately(1,4), y(22,)
```

The dataframe has 22 rows, 5 columns.  `y` could be one column (22 items).  `x` could be most of the 4 other columns, and `x_lately` the rest of `x`.

You don't describe how `x`,`y`,`x_lately` are related to the dataframe, though it looks like they might be arrays extracted from it (either as copies or views).  In any case, they cannot be `reshaped` to match the size of the dataframe.  At best they are pieces of the dataframe.

`reshape` isn't a resize or expand or pad or anything like that.  You don't even explain why want to reshape anything.

Comment: I want to reshape because i got this error: ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [21 22], i googled the error and came to the conclusion that i need to reshape. Also x, y are all from the same dataframe/arrays from the dataframe. x_lately is the forecast.

Comment: You can't reshape from 21 samples to 22.  That's not reshaping.  That's padding.  You/we need to look at that original error.

Comment: Got it let me try padding, figuring out how to do that.

Comment: using np.pad(x,[(0,0)], mode='constant') to pad and getting a tuple error:ValueError: Unable to create correctly shaped tuple from [(0, 0)]